# Android GridView imperfection, how to remove extra white space to the right

Tags: android, gridview, selector, margins

I have a GridView based calendar. I have the following XML layout with the selector set to null thus `android:listSelector="@null"` in accordance with advise I have got from this site. Now I am getting a few pixels wide strip to the right of the GridView. Why? I have tried everything I can but to avail. Here is my XML layout:

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:horizontalSpacing="-1px"
                android:numColumns="7"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:verticalSpacing="-1px"
                android:listSelector="@null" >

            </GridView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

What I get is this picture:

[image]

Comment: Maybe that is a scrollbar issue? Try setting scrollbar visibility to false.

Comment: Have you tried changing horizontal spacing from -1 to 0?

Comment: @Demonick, I tried that scroll bar issue and it didn't work. See `dinesh sharma's` answer below it seems to make sense.

Comment: you can try taking one layout inside your main layout and put your gridView inside this layout and aply android:gravity="center_horizontal" property in this layout that may help you and 1 more thing change gridView's layout_width to "wrap_content"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This space is due to imperfect calculation for each row of your grid.
For example your device width is 320 px and you have 7 rows, try any calculation that meets 320 px. If the width of each cell is 45.71428571428571 px, only then it can be reduced.

Other option

apply 
**android:gravity="center"**
 property in you grid so that spaces will equally divided from left to right

Comment: Yah, you are right @dinesh-sharma. In landscape mode the gap almost disappears proving that the problem is related to the screen dimensions. I haven't got the `android:gravity="center"` thing to work though. However, that looks rather trivial. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the `android:gravity="center"` and `android:layout_gravity="center"` solutions and they didn't work. I have a compromise solution rellies on specifing the column widths in code such that their combined width is larger that the devince's screen width. This forces the columns to fill the screen, but the last column is clipped slightly - not very good if you have a border because the border dissappears. The with is specified thus: [link]http://bytecapsule.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-empty-space-to-right-of.html (ByteCapsule)

Answer (score 4):

in my case I had horizontal spacing as 1dp

```
android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
```

so to solve this I just put the right padding as -1dp

```
android:paddingRight="-1dp"
```

even though I expected to get a space on the left side due to this , but it worked properly

Comment: I had horizontalSpacing="0dp" and this solution helped me anyway. Empty space is gone.

Comment: @Rempelos if I remember correctly, the number in the paddingRight should be -horizontalSpacing, so if you had a horizontalSpacing of 2dp then your paddingRight should be -2

Comment: @JiMMaR actually you are correct. I confused this case with mine where I had `horizontalSpacing="0dp"` and still the extra space appeared to the right, but adding just `paddingRight="-1dp"` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
```

Also you might have that space allocated for the scroll bar. 
And why do you have your vertical and horizontal spacing with negative values?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem though in my case I didn't have control over the `GridView` instance so I couldn't read the column width. Nevertheless I could subclass its container.
This isn't very orthodox but you can override the `onMeasure` method and add a few pixels. 
Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int RIGHT_MARGIN_OVERSIZE_DIP = 6;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth()
    int overSize = (int)((getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density*RIGHT_MARGIN_OVERSIZE_DIP) + 0.5f);
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width + overSize, MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec));        
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.setColumnWidth(grid.getColumnWidth()+1);
```

This will get the current ColumnWidth and add 1 pixel to it.
Remember to use this after onCreateView,since the grid needs to be initialized before that.

Also,your grid view,should use match_parent (height and width).The image/layout in the column should be also match_parent.